# React navigation mix navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Im using react-navigation to build my app, I want to have both tab and stack navigation so I did this:

```
const FindPage =  StackNavigator({
  Find: {
    screen: Find,
  },
  Item:{
    screen:Item
  }
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Find',
});

const ProfilePage =  StackNavigator({
  Profile: {
    screen: Profile,
  },
  Item:{
    screen:Item
  }
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Profile',
});

const MyApp = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Find: FindPage,
  Profile: ProfilePage
}
});

const auth = StackNavigator({
  Login:{
    screen: Login,
  },
  Register:{
    screen: Register,
  },
  Main:{
    screen: MyApp,
  }
},{
  initialRouteName: 'Main',
  headerMode: 'none'
});

export default auth;
```

But I dont get it well. this is what the screenshot  is
giving:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4swfX.png)

if you see the tab lost it tab icon and font when im using stacknavigation in tab navigation, this worked for me in another version of react nvigation and cant find anything on the web Please Help !

Comment: I deleted some design code from the tab navigation so I can post the code

Answer (score 0):

with reactnavigation2 you can achieve this like in the below code
  Read more about it here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html

```
import Ionicions from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";


screen: createBottomTabNavigator(
        {
          HomeScreen: {
            screen: HomeStack,
            navigationOptions: {
              tabBarLabel: props => <Label name="Home" {...props} />,
              tabBarIcon: props => (
                <Icon name="ios-home-outline" fillname="ios-home" {...props} />
              )
            }
          }
       })
```